# why the int variable does not have the default value?

Tags: java, initialization

In my opinion, the default value for the int variable is 0. However, in my this demo, the variable `num3` does not have the initialized value.

```
class Solution
{
    static int num1;
    int num2;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int num3;
        int[] nums = new int[5];
        System.out.println("num1: " + num1);
        Solution sol = new Solution();    
        System.out.println("num2: " + sol.num2);
        System.out.println("num3: " + num3);
        System.out.print("nums:");
        for(int item : nums)
            System.out.print(" " + item);
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

I ran my demo on Ubuntu16.04. The error I got is as follows:

```
Solution.java:12: error: variable num3 might not have been initialized
        System.out.println(num3);
                           ^
1 error
```

If I remove this line `System.out.println("num3: " + num3);`, the results I have are as follows:

```
num1: 0
num2: 0
nums: 0 0 0 0 0
```

If anyone knows why, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Because Java. Read the spec.

Comment: Variable wasn't initialized, therefore it has no value.

Comment: Java doesn't let you have uninitialized locals.

Comment: "In my opinion, the default value for the int variable is 0." Clearly, Java designers had a different opinion.

Comment: You can not no initialize a local variable because that will lead you into a compilation error

Comment: @dasblinkenlight  I updated my question. It means 'num3'.

Comment: @DejaVuSansMono  this is not the case. Please see my updated question. In most cases, the variables have the default values.

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html (my emphasis):

> ### Default Values
>
> It's not always necessary to assign a value when a field is declared.
> Fields that are declared but not initialized will be set to a
> reasonable default by the compiler. Generally speaking, this default
> will be zero or null, depending on the data type. Relying on such
> default values, however, is generally considered bad programming
> style.
>
> ...
>
> **Local variables are slightly different; the compiler never assigns a default value to an uninitialized local variable.** If you cannot initialize your local variable where it is declared, make sure to assign it a value before you attempt to use it. Accessing an uninitialized local variable will result in a compile-time error.

Comment: "Relying on such default values, however, is generally considered bad programming style."---outdated advice. IntelliJ actually has a warning "redundant initializer, 0 is the default value".

Comment: @smarx I think we also can treat the array `nums` as the local variable. However, it seems that it has the default values.

Comment: @tqjustc The *array* doesn't have a default value. It has the value you assigned (`new int[5]`).